# Switch case Java finaliza sem motivo

Tags: java, switch

Tenho um exemplo de `switch-case` com 8 opções. Porém a partir do `case` 7 ele finaliza o programa. Era para ele voltar para a opção do menu após a execução. O `case` tem limite de opções?

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TesteCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int menu = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (menu != 7) {
            System.out.println("\nMenu Principal\n");
            System.out.println(" 1) Vender Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 2) Cancelar Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 3) Relatório de Faturamento");
            System.out.println(" 4) Consultar Total de Lugares Disponíveis");
            System.out.println(" 5) Atualizar Informações do Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 6) Atualizar Informações do Co-Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 7) Atualizar Informações do Comissario");
            System.out.println(" 8) Sair do programa\n");
            menu = input.nextInt();

            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                // Aceita overbook!
                System.out.print("case1 ");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("case2 ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("case3 ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("case4 ");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("case5 ");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("case6 ");
                break;
            case 7:// a partir do 7 ele termina o programa
                System.out.println("case7 ");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("case8 ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default ");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: tente colocar no while "(menu!=8)"

Comment: Obrigada! Dei bobeira!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A linha `while (menu != 7) {` diz claramente que é para encerrar o laço quando se digita 7. Provavelmente queria usar `while (menu != 8) {`. Outra possibilidade é fazer um `while (true) {` e dentro da opção de saída usar um `break label`, assim mesmo que o número da opção de saída mude não tem que arrumar em dois lugares diferentes, assim fica mais organizado e mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Eu faria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TesteCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\nMenu Principal\n");
            System.out.println(" 1) Vender Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 2) Cancelar Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 3) Relatório de Faturamento");
            System.out.println(" 4) Consultar Total de Lugares Disponíveis");
            System.out.println(" 5) Atualizar Informações do Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 6) Atualizar Informações do Co-Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 7) Atualizar Informações do Comissario");
            System.out.println(" 8) Sair do programa\n");
            int menu = input.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                // Aceita overbook!
                System.out.print("case1 ");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("case2 ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("case3 ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("case4 ");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("case5 ");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("case6 ");
                break;
            case 7:// a partir do 7 ele termina o programa
                System.out.println("case7 ");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("case8 ");
                break finaliza;
            default:
                System.out.println("default ");
                break;
            }
        }
     finaliza:
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/BreakInSwitch.java).

Comment: Nossa! Dei bobeira!!! Obrigada!!!

Answer (score 8):

Se é a opção 8 que deve finalizar sua aplicação, o while deve checar se é diferente de 8:

```
while (menu != 8) {
            System.out.println("\nMenu Principal\n");
            System.out.println(" 1) Vender Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 2) Cancelar Passagem");
            System.out.println(" 3) Relatório de Faturamento");
            System.out.println(" 4) Consultar Total de Lugares Disponíveis");
            System.out.println(" 5) Atualizar Informações do Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 6) Atualizar Informações do Co-Piloto");
            System.out.println(" 7) Atualizar Informações do Comissario");
            System.out.println(" 8) Sair do programa\n");
            menu = input.nextInt();

            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                // Aceita overbook!
                System.out.print("case1 ");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("case2 ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("case3 ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("case4 ");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("case5 ");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("case6 ");
                break;
            case 7:// a partir do 7 ele termina o programa
                System.out.println("case7 ");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("case8 ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default ");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Você pode mudar pra `do..while` também, uma vez que se trata de um menu, e, ao menos uma vez, ele será executado:

```
do {

        System.out.println("\nMenu Principal\n");
        System.out.println(" 1) Vender Passagem");
        System.out.println(" 2) Cancelar Passagem");
        System.out.println(" 3) Relatório de Faturamento");
        System.out.println(" 4) Consultar Total de Lugares Disponíveis");
        System.out.println(" 5) Atualizar Informações do Piloto");
        System.out.println(" 6) Atualizar Informações do Co-Piloto");
        System.out.println(" 7) Atualizar Informações do Comissario");
        System.out.println(" 8) Sair do programa\n");
        menu = input.nextInt();

        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            // Aceita overbook!
            System.out.print("case1 ");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("case2 ");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("case3 ");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("case4 ");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("case5 ");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("case6 ");
            break;
        case 7:// a partir do 7 ele termina o programa
            System.out.println("case7 ");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("case8 ");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("default ");
            break;
        }
}while (menu != 8);
```