# Break e Continue no Switch

Tags: java, switch, break

Qual a diferença de usar o `break` e o `continue` dentro do `switch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `switch` em si não aceita um `continue`, mas aceita `break`, o que pode ser um pouco confuso porque os laços de repetição `while`, `do ... while`, `for`, `for :` aceitam ambos comando de controle fluxo que determinam um desvio para o fim do laço.

Em uma laço o `continue` vai para o fim mas se mantém dentro dele a não ser que a condição de repetição mande sair. O ´break` faz sair do laço em qualquer situação.

Mas você quer saber do `switch` que é um comando de controle de fluxo de seleção e não repetição. O `break` nessa construção faz sair de todo o `switch`. O normal de cada `case` é executar o que está dentro se atendeu a condição e ir para o próximo `case`. Se nada for feito ele tentará analisar todos os `case`. Ele não tem um curto-circuito automático. Só que na maioria dos casos não é o que deseja. É comum que se entrar em um dos `case` você não queira mais verificar qualquer outro `case`, inclusive porque é improvável que algum atenda a condição. A forma de encerrar é com o `break`. Se não usar ocorre o chamado *fallthrough* automático.

Isto é considerado um erro por muitos, mas é assim que as linguagens escolheram funcionar. Melhor seria se a quebra fosse automática e o *fallthrough* fosse obrigatoriamente explícito.

Então é um infortúnio que se você quiser sair de um laço de repetição com um `break` e o código estiver dentro de um `switch`, o `break` não sairá do *loop*, só sairá do seletor. Aí teria que fazer algum controle extra, ou se a linguagem permitir, Java é uma delas, usar um `break *label*`. Tem uma [resposta em Kotlin sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227419/101), mas serve mais ou menos igual para o Java.

Uma alternativa, nem sempre boa é usar um `if` em sequência, assim o `break´ tem a semântica do laço normal, se for necessário usá-lo para isso.

Em alguns casos um `return` pode ser a solução quando precisa encerrar, afinal métodos bem escritos são curtos e provavelmente se é para sair de um `switch` e de um laço, também é para sair do método.

Tem uma [pergunta com um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146875/101) ([outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240410/101)). E tem um exemplo, ainda que em C#, mas é a mesma coisa, para o não uso do `break`, é como se tivesse um `continue` implícito. Por isso o `continue` não é usado.

Falei mais [sobre ele em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/282675/101). E [como ele funciona internamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101) (o Java é um pouco diferente, mas não muito).

Veja exemplo:

```
class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            if (x == 6) continue;
            if (x == 8) break;
            switch (x) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("zero");
                continue;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("um");
                continue;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("dois");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xaVhby). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mlxqdaby-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/BreakOnSwitch.java).